# не отрабатывает скрипт при раскрытии меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

есть меню, не раскрывается основной каталог

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('body').on('click','.fa-angle-down', toggleParent ); 
 function toggleParent() { 
  $(this) 
    .parents('.item.parent')
    .toggleClass('active')
    .parents('.sub-menu') 
    .toggleClass('open'); 
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
 } 
});
```

```css
.menuIndex{
        display: grid;
    }
.menuIndex .item {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
.menuIndex>.item>a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        color: #707070;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
    }
.menuIndex .item.parent>a {
        position: relative;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #f0f5f8;
        color: #707070;
        font-size: 16px;
        outline: none;
        font-weight: 300;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
    }
.menuIndex .item.parent.active>a{
        background-color: #d9eaf4;
        color: #000;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>a:first-of-type{
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu>.item.parent>.fa-angle-down{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 15px;
        color: #609c60;
        top: 0;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 45px;
        display: block;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu>.item>.fa-angle-down.active{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        text-align: right;
        display: flex;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent>.fa-angle-down {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 45px;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 15px;
        line-height: 2.1em;
        color: #609c60;
        font-size: 20px;
        top: 0;
        height: 45px;
        display: block;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent>.fa-angle-down.active {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        text-align: right;
        display: flex;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu>a {
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: initial;
        color: #707070;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 35px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        background: #d9eaf4;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item.parent {
        height: auto;
    }
    .menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>a{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    
.menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu,header .menu .menuIndex .items.parent>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu{
        display: none;
    }
.menuIndex .item.parent a:after{
        content:"";
    }
.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu{
        display: none;
    }
.menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu.open, header .menu .menuIndex .items.parent>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu.open {
        display: grid;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/094f305d52.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menuIndex">
    <div class="item parent">
              <a href="" class="noLink">Каталог</a>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div class="item parent">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <nav class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="">Мука</a>
                        <a href="">Крупы</a>
                        <a href="">Сахар</a>
                        <a href="">Греча</a>
                      </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="item parent">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <nav class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="">Мука</a>
                        <a href="">Крупы</a>
                        <a href="">Сахар</a>
                        <a href="">Греча</a>
                      </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              
            <div class="item">  
              <a href="">Доставка</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="">О нас</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="">Магазины</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="">Новости</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="">Вакансии</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="">Рецепты</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="">Контакты</a>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.parents('.sub-menu')` - вот это ну никак не может найти **потомка**

`find` - может помочь

```js
$('body').on('click', '.fa-angle-down', toggleParent);

function toggleParent() {
  $(this)
    .parents('.item.parent')
    .toggleClass('active')
    .find('.sub-menu')
    .toggleClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
}
```

```css
.menuIndex {
  display: grid;
}

.menuIndex .item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.menuIndex>.item>a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f5f8;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent.active>a {
  background-color: #d9eaf4;
  color: #000;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>a:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu>.item.parent>.fa-angle-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #609c60;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 45px;
  display: block;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu>.item>.fa-angle-down.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>.fa-angle-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 2.1em;
  color: #609c60;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 0;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>.fa-angle-down.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu>a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: initial;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d9eaf4;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item.parent {
  height: auto;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>a {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu,
header .menu .menuIndex .items.parent>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent a:after {
  content: "";
}

.menuIndex .item.parent:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menuIndex .item.parent>.sub-menu.open,
header .menu .menuIndex .items.parent>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu.open {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/094f305d52.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menuIndex">
  <div class="item parent">
    <a href="" class="noLink">Каталог</a>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="item parent">
        <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <nav class="sub-menu">
          <a href="">Мука</a>
          <a href="">Крупы</a>
          <a href="">Сахар</a>
          <a href="">Греча</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item parent">
        <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <nav class="sub-menu">
          <a href="">Мука</a>
          <a href="">Крупы</a>
          <a href="">Сахар</a>
          <a href="">Греча</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">Доставка</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">О нас</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">Магазины</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">Новости</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">Вакансии</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">Рецепты</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">Контакты</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```